# Why don't responses on meta SO come as notifications to my inbox?

Tags: discussion, status-norepro

When I get comments on other StackExchange sites, they don't come to my inbox. Why is this so?

Comment: So you did not get notification for this comment?

Answer (score 2):

This actually does happen for me:

[image: inbox excerpt with SO and MSO comments]

The icons are site icons and you can see I have both SO and MSO comments in my inbox. Your inbox is maintained across all SE sites; when I click the 'more inbox messages' link at the bottom you are taken to your full inbox on stackexchange.com; here is a shot of a few messages from different sites in mine:

[image: SE inbox excerpt]

All these messages have appeared in my inbox at the top of every SE site at the time.

<sup><sub>I do apologize for the lack of hand-drawn circles on these screenshots though. I didn't see much point. :-)</sub></sup>

Answer (score 2):

You *are* getting them, I can see them! I call shenanigans!

Seriously though, they are there and I can see your inbox with many meta responses in it...tagging this as [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro).

Comment: @MartijnPieters - added more fun! I'm up early to kick an out of control load balancer and feed a baby at the same time, I blame craziness on no-sleepy